# Selecting and separating elements from a list

Tags: r

I have a list of names in a list, such as:

```
site <- list("site2-site22" ,"site2-site45", "site4-site2", 
             "site6-site2","site9-site4", "site20-site6", 
             "site25-site272", "site32-site47","site62-site74", 
             "site272-site280")
```

From the list, for example, I need to select those elements which has site2 in it, either before or after -

and put them in a separate list,

I can use grep command as below:

```
grep("^site2-|-site2$",site,value=T)
```

and save them all in a separate list.

In a similar way I need to select for all other sites: site2, site3, site4, etc. and save them in a separate list for each site, but is there a way with a single command to separate them and save each in different lists?

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using the functions `paste` and `lapply` to build the string pattern to match against and then apply `grep` over each site? Something like this:

```
site <- list("site2-site22" ,"site2-site45", "site4-site2", 
             "site6-site2","site9-site4", "site20-site6", 
             "site25-site272", "site32-site47","site62-site74", 
             "site272-site280")

l <- paste("site",c(2,4,6),sep="")

myFun <- function(x,siteList){
    pat <- paste("^",x,"-|-",x,"$",sep="")
    grep(pat,siteList,value = TRUE)
}

lapply(l,FUN = myFun, siteList = site)
```

which returns this:

```
[[1]] [1] "site2-site22" "site2-site45" "site4-site2"  "site6-site2" 

[[2]] [1] "site4-site2" "site9-site4"

[[3]] [1] "site6-site2"  "site20-site6"
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I don't know of a single command, but a single line could be:

```
lapply(1:5, function(i) grep(paste("^site",i,"-|-site",i,"$", sep=""),site,value=T))
```

...and then of course modify the `1:5` to suit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

First, make a vector of all the possible sites, if you don't already have that.  I give the site its own name to make things better labeled later.

```
sites <- unique(unlist(strsplit(unlist(site), "-")))
names(sites) <- sites
```

Then you can use the `plyr` library to loop over this and run the `grep` for each site, building the grep string using `paste`.

```
library("plyr")

llply(sites, function(s) {grep(paste("^",s,"-|-",s,"$",sep=""), site, value=TRUE)})
```